# How many ways to color a graph with 10 colors

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Assume that we have ten colors to choose from. Assume that the vertices are distinguishable. How many ways are there to color the following graph? (A coloring of a graph is a painting of the vertices such that neighbors receive different colors)

[image]

What is an efficient way to approach this problem? Can I separate this situation into different cases?

Case 1: using 3 colors (this is the minimum number of colors needed to color this graph)

Case 2: using 4 colors

...

Case 7: using 9 colors (this is the maximum number of colors since there are 9 vertices)

Comment: The standard technique is deletion-contraction. Let $\chi$ be the chromatic polynomial. Then $\chi(G,k) = \chi(G-uv,k) + \chi(G/uv,k)$ where $k$ is the number of colors and for any edge $uv$ of $G$, $G-uv$ is the subgraph of $G$ with $uv$ deleted and $G/uv$ is the graph given from $G$ after contracting $uv$. You can use this to eliminate cycles since paths can be computed directly.

Answer (score 2):

Start by counting the number of ways to color the triangle.  If you have $n$ colors available, you have $n$ choices for the $4$-way vertex, $n-1$ for the one above it, and $n-2$ choices  for the third.  Think about how many choices you have for each of the others.  You will get a $9^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial in $n$.

Comment: Every other vertex would have 9 or n-1 possibilities. So for this problem my answer would be $10\times 9^7 \times 8$?

Comment: That is right....